# YAML azure-pipelines.yml syntax to add azureSubscription for all steps

Tags: scala, azure-devops, sbt

I need to add `azureSubscription: 'AWSMavenReadOnly'` "globally" for all of the steps.  I am trying to avoid the full `task` syntax.  How would I add this as an input for all of these scripts?

```yaml
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml
trigger:
- master
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
steps:
- script: sbt clean
  displayName: 'Running $ sbt clean'
- script: sbt update
  displayName: 'Running $ sbt update'
- script: sbt compile
  displayName: 'Running $ sbt compile'
- script: sbt test
  displayName: 'Running $ sbt test'
```

Answer (score 1):

I kind of got this working with:

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml
trigger:
- master
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
steps:
- task: AWSShellScript@1
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'AWSMavenReadOnly'
    regionName: 'eu-central-1'
    scriptType: 'inline'
    inlineScript: 'sbt clean update compile'
  displayName: 'Running $ sbt clean update compile'
- task: AWSShellScript@1
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'AWSMavenReadOnly'
    regionName: 'eu-central-1'
    scriptType: 'inline'
    inlineScript: 'sbt test'
  displayName: 'Running $ sbt test'
```

Now I need to figure out howto use the java11 instead of the default jre available on `ubuntu-latest`

Comment: Good job! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. (A reminder of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer))

Comment: I guess I wasn't sure if this is the "right way" to do it or not, does it look right?  Is there a more straightforward way to get/use the `awsCredentials` in a normal bash task?

Comment: Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops), azure devops service recommends using template to reuse similar tasks. But since your tasks have different content, I think there's no better way than the way above. So I suggest you can feel free to [accept it as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) :)